# Disable validation for an element with jQuery Unobtrusive Validation

Tags: jquery, unobtrusive-validation

I am generating a list of elements on a page, and they all have validators attached to them. When I look in the HTML source, I see something like:

```html
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" data-val-required="No valid email address!" data-val="true">
```

I need a way to dynamically enable/disable the validation for such an element. I tried to enable/disable the `data-val` attribute by setting it to `false` and then back to `true`. But it doesn't seem to response to that; the validation is always there!

Does anyone have any idea how I can enable/disable validators on certain fields dynamically?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I actually found a solution that fits my needs better. I can do the following:

```
$(function() {
    var settngs = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
    settngs.ignore = ".ignore";
});
```

And with that i can 'toggle' any element that i want by adding or removing the classname `ignore` from an element.

Comment: note that to keep the default jquery validation behavior you should put `settings.ignore = ":hidden, .ignore"` Personally I prefer to add `:disabled` also

Comment: Source: http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/07/13/overriding-unobtrusive-client-side-validation-settings-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

Comment: Doesn't disable it for me.

Comment: Does not work in some cases. So I had to dig into source and found solution that works 100%:
`$("form").each(function () {`
        `var data = $.data(this, 'validator');`
        `if (data && data.settings) {`
            `data.settings.ignore = '.ign';`
            `data.settings.onclick = void(0);`
            `data.settings.onfocusin = void(0);`
            `data.settings.onfocusout = void(0);`
            `data.settings.onkeyup = void(0);`
            `data.settings.onsubmit = void (0);`
        `}`
    `});`

Comment: `$.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings` returns nothing in my case...

Comment: For those who want to disable validation on all elements in form: just write `settngs.ignore = "*";` It works because `*` is universal selector that match all elements.

Comment: Trick question: if the error message was shown before disabling validation and that once disabled, the style won't be toggled, how would you hide the error messages on the page? (Note that summary is correclty updated).

Answer (score 15):

I think this will help.

```
<div class="editor-field">
       @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BatchId, new { @class = "k-textbox" })
       @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(true); }
</div>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! 2 years more recent than the other

Comment: @JavierIEH This answer may be newer, and may have worked for you, but it only works at page render time. Anyone wanting to enable/disable the validators on the fly client side will still need to use the earlier answer.

Comment: Well answer may vary depending on the problem the user has

Comment: I think the key here is knowing what the Html.EnableClientValidation(false) actually outputs in html when the page is rendered.

Comment: Okay, so trying this in mvc4, not only did it not work, but it added no additional attributes to the input field.

Answer (score 2):

I would add one more option without overriding unobtrusive validator defaults. As validation for specific element is controled by `data-val` attribute, you can set it as `data-val="false"`.

So for Razor helper, use:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.DateOfBirth, new { @class = "form-control", data_val = false })
```

and for new .net core syntax, use:

```
<input asp-for="DateOfBirth" class="form-control" data-val="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked better for me:

```
$('#Reference').rules('add', 'required');
$('#Reference').rules('add', 'remove');
$('#Reference').rules('add', { minlength: 2 });
```