# Validation using data annotations with multiple submit buttons

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, model-view-controller

I have view with multiple submit button in ASP.NET MVC and I want validate the form using data annotations, but when user clicks on a particular button, not all submit button, validation must be performed with particular button not all button on view.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Skill", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SkillName)
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SkillId)
   @Html.ValidataionSummaryFor(model => model.SkillName)

   <input type="submit" name="AddAction" value="Add" id="btnAdd"/>
   <input type="button" name="btnreset" value="Reset" />
}
```

I want that validation will apply only on Add button not on Next button or any button

Answer (score 0):

You can you put "NoValidation" Buttons outside form. This will solve the issue.
If you still need form data, you can serialize it via JS, like this:

```
$("form").serialize()
```

and send to server.

Comment: but how can i decide that validation must perform on this particular button while i use $("form").serialize() please help thanks a lot

Comment: @Riyaz Well, if you really want to turn off validation with js, one of the ways here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7391785/1849444
or here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12179373/1849444

Comment: Thanks a lot,But i don't want to turn off validation but want to apply validation when user click only particular button